# A generic Topic content widget

Tags: nopcommerce

I have been adding topic content areas to my pages by adding

```
@Html.Action("TopicBlock", "Topic", new { systemName = "OrderDetailsProductsBottom" })
```

I've noticed that everywhere I've been adding these topic actions there is a WidgetZone conveniently placed above it.

Is adding topic content to a widget zone possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is valid. But widget and Topic are created to serve 2 different purpose.

Using topic action, you can render any Content page in any part of nopcommerce. You can control content from content management screen of admin.

Widgets are designed to render in specific html data on predefined widgets area to serve a specific purpose. So if you want to render many html's (topic), you may end-up with many widgets.

Hope it clarify both purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jeyara, I kinda figured that was the intent. However, like other lightweight CMS solutions it seems HTML could be treated like any other module and added to these widgets. This would be a huge improvement IMO.